# "\overline" command in align environment is creating strange characters

Tags: math-mode, align

I am trying to print a bar over the symbol "v." Weirdly, every time I try to do so, I get these strange set theoretic-looking characters:

[image]

My code is the following:

```latex
\begin{align}
\mathcal_{F_{\lor}} (\overline v(\alpha),
\overline v(\beta)) && \text{Def. of conjunction} \\
\mathcal_{F_{\lor}} (\text{T}, \overline v(\beta)) && \text{Def of $v$} \\
= \text{T} && \text{Def. of $\mathcal_{F_{\lor}}$}
\end{align}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Welcome! There are several issues, such as `\mathcal` followed by a `_`. Does `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_{\lor} (\overline{v}(\alpha),
\overline v(\beta)) && \text{Def. of conjunction} \\
\mathcal{F}_{\lor} (\text{T}, \overline v(\beta)) && \text{Def of $v$} \\
= \text{T} && \text{Def.\ of $\mathcal{F}_{\lor}$}
\end{align}
\end{document}` come close to what you want to achieve?

Comment: please always show a small document that reproduces the problem `\mathcal_` is `\mathcal{_}`  so the argument to `\mathcal` is just a subscript marker `_` with no base or subscript, which presumably generates errors, after an error the typeset output is not intended to be useful

Comment: Thank you both! Resolved.